# How do I copy a URL into my form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I need to create a popup form that will take the URL of the page the popup link is on and insert it into a form. From there I want to send it to a customer service rep.

Is there a way I can grab the URL and $_POST it to my php function?

Answer (score 2):

quick/dirty:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('url').value = document.location;">
<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: OK, that almost does what I need. think of it this way, I have a product page which has a popup link. click the link and a form opens for a customer to fill out. when they post that form I'd also like to have the URL of the product page. using this I get the URL of the form.

Comment: @ScottMorrison Probably gonna have to use `parent` location, something to the affect of `document.parent.location`.

Comment: the current document (your form) will not have any knowledge of any previous pages, except possibly via the HTTP referer, which is NOT a reliable source of data.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand which url you are looking for but for the same page's url you can use:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
?>
```

after that you can add the url like so :

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="<?php echo $currentURL.'?'.$query; ?>" />
```

For more info you can take a look at:

```
<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
```

Comment: sorry, I'm looking for the URL of the original page, not the popup form.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for you but have you tried using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. This should work in anything other than IE

Comment: @ScottMorrison You probably can use the code and use `HTTP_REFERER` instead.

Comment: @lexmihaylov - LOL, I think we posted the same answer at the same time haha!

Comment: @lexmihaylov You must've beat me by `1500ms` ;-)

Comment: If http_referer doesn't work in IE then I'd rather not use it (hate to have to say that)

Comment: @ScottMorrison Gawd, all the `good stuff` hardly or never works with (groan) IE.

Comment: I'm reading about this and I'm coming across a lot of recommendations to us a session variable. guess I'll have to bite the bullet and figure that out.

Comment: your best bet is to pass it into the popup from the requesting page via a get parameter.

Comment: well another way would be to use window.opener.location.href and replace it in the 1st answer.

Comment: @Orangepill, could you elaborate?

Comment: Another thing you could do, is to set a hidden field as the url, in a preset fashion if I could say.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for document.URL.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_url.asp

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted you. If its just for the w3schools link, I think that's a bit unfair. The link *does* adequately describe `document.URL`, which looks like a valid approach to OP's question. +1 to bring you back to 0.

Comment: @ZachL  I down-voted this answer. because it doesn't answer the question and is considered as `Link-only`  answer!

Comment: Agree to disagree? It at least partly answers the question, and IMO is not really subject to the `link-only answer` stigma since the answer content is right here. `document.URL` - which is pretty self-explanatory. The link is just supplementary.